# Pre-load a program in VBScript for more efficient execution

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBS script (compiled to an .exe, actually) that invokes another program (.exe) using the VBS *Run* instruction. My mainframe mentality tells me that it would be beneficial to pre-load this second program at the start of my script, so that it is available immediately when needed further down the line. Typically on mainframe, when appropriate, one would LOAD the program into memory at some point and then branch to it later.

Does this concept exist in VBS?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can't pre-load an executable you're launching via Run (or any other way) in VBScript.

Comment: That's clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to start a program in a suspended state, but I have still not found a way to later resume the execution without a external tool (we need to call [`ResumeThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API). For this sample I have used the Windows SysInternal's [`PsSuspend`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pssuspend.aspx) tool to resume the process.

```vbs
Option Explicit

Const SW_NORMAL = 1
Const CF_CREATE_SUSPENDED = 4

Const PROCESS_NAME = "Notepad.exe"

' Instantiate required objects
Dim wmi, shell
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Prepare the startup configuration for the process
' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Dim startUp
    Set startUp = wmi.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup").SpawnInstance_
    With startUp
        .ShowWindow = SW_NORMAL
        .CreateFlags = CF_CREATE_SUSPENDED
    End With 

' Start the process
' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx    
Dim retCode, processID
    retCode = wmi.Get("Win32_Process").Create( PROCESS_NAME, Null, startUp, processID )

    If retCode <> 0 Then
        Wscript.Echo "Process creation failed: " & retCode 
        WScript.Quit 1
    End If 
    WScript.Echo "Process created with PID: " & processID

' Ask the OS to check for presence of our process    
    WScript.Echo shell.Exec("tasklist /fo:list /v /fi ""imagename eq " & PROCESS_NAME & """").StdOut.ReadAll()

' Wait (not required, just for testing) 
    WScript.Sleep 5000

' Resume the process - SysInternals pssuspend required
' https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pssuspend.aspx
    Call shell.Run("pssuspend64.exe /accepteula -r " & processID, 0, False)

' Wait for the process to resume and show again the task list 
    WScript.Sleep 2000
    WScript.Echo shell.Exec("tasklist /fo:list /v /fi ""imagename eq " & PROCESS_NAME & """").StdOut.ReadAll()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I suspect the overhead may exceed the benefits, especially since...

I've been using one of two ways to compile scripts:

1. VBSEdit
2. VBS_to_exe

I started to use the latter exclusively after I noticed that it produced files much smaller than the former. However, while pursuing the issue of my original post here, (prompted by noticeable delay when I executed my script (created by VBS-to_exe)), I re-compiled the script using VBSEdit, and lo and behold, the delay is reduced substantially, to the point where it becomes essentially a non-issue.

I am satisfied:)

Comment: @BillFriedman, While not finding a pure wmi native way of doing it, there is almost no benefit (depending on the exact executable).  I found the question interesting and decided to test and post what i found. Thank you for your proposal of a different approach.